# Bing Map Repeating Tiles

Tags: c#, winforms, bing-maps, bing

I ran into a issue were the tile on the Bing Map repeat themselves for a given coordinate. Has anyone seen this issue? Its bizarre. The application is .net 3.5, C# and Win Forms. The API key for Bing maps is valid and the service URL used is http://dev.virtualearth.net/webservices/v1/imageryservice/imageryservice.svc

Any help with this is appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Haven't seen this before and can't reproduce it. Are you sure you are using the SOAP imagery service and not the WPF map control or something else? Are you stitching the images together? It could be related to this: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/618e5f6c-7222-446f-b738-7f57a2e2b592/new-url-templates-for-bing-maps-tiles?forum=bingmapsservices but I haven't seen anyone report this type of issue. Can you provide some more info?

Comment: yes I am using the http://dev.virtualearth.net/webservices/v1/imageryservice/imageryservice.svc url with a token. i will  look at the above msdn link and see if I can find help there

Comment: I am making a request to the following and it appears the map tile defaults to the above tile image for every request made. http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/V1/Imagery/Metadata/Aerial/38,-97?zl=15&key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&o=xml

Comment: Are you sure you are using Tokens. Tokens were deprecated years ago. You should be passing a Bing Maps key into the ApplicationId property of the credentials.

Comment: Right I will put my answer in below, its all a little odd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok what happen is when the request to Bing Maps fails I take the lat and long for the map of the US. I try to use these coords to generate the US map, this work "ok" except I only get the single tile back in the requsst.